# android - is any differences exits between emulator and device

Tags: android

My application is working properly in the emulator. In Case of Device it is not working properly. it means application is running but in middle of the application it is  forcibly stoped. after that i am getting the NPE(Null Pointer Exception). Why it's came? is any differences exits between emulator and device when the running of application. please can anybody help me.

thanks

Comment: Please specify what error you get when your application force close..

Comment: @naresh - I recommend that you plug in your device to Eclipse and debug directly. See: [http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: @ Chirag Raval -application forcibly closed in the device not in the emulator. I don't know how to see the error in the device. My Device is Samsung Galaxy Apollo GT-i5801.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many differences for nexus devices, but for 99% of Android phones out there, the manufacturers mess up a lot of stuff. Sorry.